# Dynamically change a mapped list style property inside a react component

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic, jsx

I've got a defautProps array of all the named colors that I'm displaying in an unordered list by mapping and filtering. I'm already displaying each color name but I'd like to use that named color as the backgroundColor for an inline style tag. Unsuccessful inline stylecode is included below. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
class JSexp extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filterBy: ''
    };
  }

  filterColors = () => {
    const clr = document.getElementById('filter').value;
    this.setState({ filterBy: clr})
  }

  getColor = (idx) => {
    return this.props.allColors[idx]
  }

  render () {
    const arr = this.props.allColors;
    const filterBy = clr => clr.includes(this.state.filterBy);
    const backgroundColor = this.getColor(16)


    const style = {
      width: '20px',
      height: '20px',
      backgroundColor: this.getColor({idx})
    }

    const colors = arr.filter(filterBy).map((color, idx) =>
    (
        <li key={idx}>{color} <div style={style} id={idx} /> </li>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Named Colors</h3>
        <ul>
          {colors}
        </ul>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by" id="filter" onChange={this.filterColors}></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

JSexp.defaultProps = {
  allColors: ["AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", "Aqua", "Aquamarine", "Azure", "Beige", "Bisque", "Black", "BlanchedAlmond",
    "Blue", "BlueViolet", "Brown", "BurlyWood", "CadetBlue", "Chartreuse", "Chocolate",
    "Coral", "CornflowerBlue", "Cornsilk", "Crimson", "Cyan", "DarkBlue", "DarkCyan", "DarkGoldenRod",
    "DarkGray", "DarkGrey", "DarkGreen", "DarkKhaki", "DarkMagenta", "DarkOliveGreen", "Darkorange",
    "DarkOrchid", "DarkRed", "DarkSalmon", "DarkSeaGreen", "DarkSlateBlue", "DarkSlateGray", "DarkSlateGrey",
    "DarkTurquoise", "DarkViolet", "DeepPink", "DeepSkyBlue", "DimGray", "DimGrey", "DodgerBlue",
    "FireBrick", "FloralWhite", "ForestGreen", "Fuchsia", "Gainsboro", "GhostWhite", "Gold", "GoldenRod",
    "Gray", "Grey", "Green", "GreenYellow", "HoneyDew", "HotPink", "IndianRed", "Indigo", "Ivory", "Khaki",
    "Lavender", "LavenderBlush", "LawnGreen", "LemonChiffon", "LightBlue", "LightCoral", "LightCyan",
    "LightGoldenRodYellow", "LightGray", "LightGrey", "LightGreen", "LightPink", "LightSalmon",
    "LightSeaGreen", "LightSkyBlue", "LightSlateGray", "LightSlateGrey", "LightSteelBlue", "LightYellow",
    "Lime", "LimeGreen", "Linen", "Magenta", "Maroon", "MediumAquaMarine", "MediumBlue", "MediumOrchid",
    "MediumPurple", "MediumSeaGreen", "MediumSlateBlue", "MediumSpringGreen", "MediumTurquoise",
    "MediumVioletRed", "MidnightBlue", "MintCream", "MistyRose", "Moccasin", "NavajoWhite", "Navy",
    "OldLace", "Olive", "OliveDrab", "Orange", "OrangeRed", "Orchid", "PaleGoldenRod", "PaleGreen",
    "PaleTurquoise", "PaleVioletRed", "PapayaWhip", "PeachPuff", "Peru", "Pink", "Plum", "PowderBlue",
    "Purple", "Red", "RosyBrown", "RoyalBlue", "SaddleBrown", "Salmon", "SandyBrown", "SeaGreen",
    "SeaShell", "Sienna", "Silver", "SkyBlue", "SlateBlue", "SlateGray", "SlateGrey", "Snow", "SpringGreen",
    "SteelBlue", "Tan", "Teal", "Thistle", "Tomato", "Turquoise", "Violet", "Wheat", "White", "WhiteSmoke",
    "Yellow", "YellowGreen"]
};
```

Comment: What version of react are you using? I'm running across a few problems with your code here. Does the above snippet run for you locally? Can you re-create in codesandbox.io?

Comment: I did figure out what I did wrong. You can view the working code here:   https://3l7q41026.codesandbox.io/

Comment: Awesome mate. I see i see...

Answer (score 0):

here

```
const style = {
  width: '20px',
  height: '20px',
  backgroundColor: this.getColor({idx})
}
```

seems like you are missing {idx} value.

Try

```
const colors = arr.filter(filterBy).map((color, idx) => {
    const style = {
      width: '20px',
      height: '20px',
      backgroundColor: this.getColor({idx})
    }

    return <li key={idx}>{color} <div style={style} id={idx} /> </li>
)});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can assign the backgroundColor of the div when you do the mapping of the array.

```js
class JSexp extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filterBy: ''
    };
  }

  filterColors = (e) => {
    this.setState({ filterBy: e.target.value})
  }


  render () {
    const arr = this.props.allColors;
    const filterBy = clr => clr.includes(this.state.filterBy);

    const colors = arr.filter(filterBy).map((color, idx) =>
        <li key={idx}>
          {color}
          <div style={{width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor: color}}>
          </div>
        </li>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by" id="filter" onChange={this.filterColors}></input>
 
        <h3>Named Colors</h3>
        <ul>
          {colors}
        </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }
}


JSexp.defaultProps = {
  allColors: ["AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", "Aqua", "Aquamarine", "Azure", "Beige", "Bisque", "Black", "BlanchedAlmond",
    "Blue", "BlueViolet", "Brown", "BurlyWood", "CadetBlue", "Chartreuse", "Chocolate",
    "Coral", "CornflowerBlue", "Cornsilk", "Crimson", "Cyan", "DarkBlue", "DarkCyan", "DarkGoldenRod",
    "DarkGray", "DarkGrey", "DarkGreen", "DarkKhaki", "DarkMagenta", "DarkOliveGreen", "Darkorange",
    "DarkOrchid", "DarkRed", "DarkSalmon", "DarkSeaGreen", "DarkSlateBlue", "DarkSlateGray", "DarkSlateGrey",
    "DarkTurquoise", "DarkViolet", "DeepPink", "DeepSkyBlue", "DimGray", "DimGrey", "DodgerBlue",
    "FireBrick", "FloralWhite", "ForestGreen", "Fuchsia", "Gainsboro", "GhostWhite", "Gold", "GoldenRod",
    "Gray", "Grey", "Green", "GreenYellow", "HoneyDew", "HotPink", "IndianRed", "Indigo", "Ivory", "Khaki",
    "Lavender", "LavenderBlush", "LawnGreen", "LemonChiffon", "LightBlue", "LightCoral", "LightCyan",
    "LightGoldenRodYellow", "LightGray", "LightGrey", "LightGreen", "LightPink", "LightSalmon",
    "LightSeaGreen", "LightSkyBlue", "LightSlateGray", "LightSlateGrey", "LightSteelBlue", "LightYellow",
    "Lime", "LimeGreen", "Linen", "Magenta", "Maroon", "MediumAquaMarine", "MediumBlue", "MediumOrchid",
    "MediumPurple", "MediumSeaGreen", "MediumSlateBlue", "MediumSpringGreen", "MediumTurquoise",
    "MediumVioletRed", "MidnightBlue", "MintCream", "MistyRose", "Moccasin", "NavajoWhite", "Navy",
    "OldLace", "Olive", "OliveDrab", "Orange", "OrangeRed", "Orchid", "PaleGoldenRod", "PaleGreen",
    "PaleTurquoise", "PaleVioletRed", "PapayaWhip", "PeachPuff", "Peru", "Pink", "Plum", "PowderBlue",
    "Purple", "Red", "RosyBrown", "RoyalBlue", "SaddleBrown", "Salmon", "SandyBrown", "SeaGreen",
    "SeaShell", "Sienna", "Silver", "SkyBlue", "SlateBlue", "SlateGray", "SlateGrey", "Snow", "SpringGreen",
    "SteelBlue", "Tan", "Teal", "Thistle", "Tomato", "Turquoise", "Violet", "Wheat", "White", "WhiteSmoke",
    "Yellow", "YellowGreen"]
};

ReactDOM.render(<JSexp />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a good night sleep I did figure out what the problem was. It was actually a lot easier than I thought:

```
class NamedColors extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filterBy: ''
    };
  }

  filterColors = () => {
    const clr = document.getElementById('filter').value;
    this.setState({ filterBy: clr })
  }

  render() {

    const itemStyle = {
      fontSize: '.85rem',
      padding: '5px'
    }

    const contentDisplay = {
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      padding: '5px'
    }

    const contentHeader = {
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'baseline'
    }

    const arr = this.props.allColors;

    const filterBy = (strToFilter) => {
      return strToFilter.includes(this.state.filterBy)
    };

    const colors = arr.filter(filterBy).map((color, idx) =>
      (
        <div key={idx + 10}>
          <div key={idx} style={itemStyle}>
            {color}
            <div style={
              {
                backgroundColor: color,
                width: '150px',
                height: '32.5px',
                border: 'solid',
                borderWidth: '1px'
              }
            } />
          </div>
        </div>
      ));

    return (
      <div>
        <div style={contentHeader}>
          <h3>Named Colors</h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by" id="filter" onChange={this.filterColors}></input>
        </div>
        <div style={contentDisplay}>
          {colors}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

NamedColors.defaultProps = {
  allColors: ["AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", "Aqua", "Aquamarine", "Azure", "Beige", "Bisque", "Black", "BlanchedAlmond",
    "Blue", "BlueViolet", "Brown", "BurlyWood", "CadetBlue", "Chartreuse", "Chocolate",
    "Coral", "CornflowerBlue", "Cornsilk", "Crimson", "Cyan", "DarkBlue", "DarkCyan", "DarkGoldenRod",
    "DarkGray", "DarkGrey", "DarkGreen", "DarkKhaki", "DarkMagenta", "DarkOliveGreen", "Darkorange",
    "DarkOrchid", "DarkRed", "DarkSalmon", "DarkSeaGreen", "DarkSlateBlue", "DarkSlateGray", "DarkSlateGrey",
    "DarkTurquoise", "DarkViolet", "DeepPink", "DeepSkyBlue", "DimGray", "DimGrey", "DodgerBlue",
    "FireBrick", "FloralWhite", "ForestGreen", "Fuchsia", "Gainsboro", "GhostWhite", "Gold", "GoldenRod",
    "Gray", "Grey", "Green", "GreenYellow", "HoneyDew", "HotPink", "IndianRed", "Indigo", "Ivory", "Khaki",
    "Lavender", "LavenderBlush", "LawnGreen", "LemonChiffon", "LightBlue", "LightCoral", "LightCyan",
    "LightGoldenRodYellow", "LightGray", "LightGrey", "LightGreen", "LightPink", "LightSalmon",
    "LightSeaGreen", "LightSkyBlue", "LightSlateGray", "LightSlateGrey", "LightSteelBlue", "LightYellow",
    "Lime", "LimeGreen", "Linen", "Magenta", "Maroon", "MediumAquaMarine", "MediumBlue", "MediumOrchid",
    "MediumPurple", "MediumSeaGreen", "MediumSlateBlue", "MediumSpringGreen", "MediumTurquoise",
    "MediumVioletRed", "MidnightBlue", "MintCream", "MistyRose", "Moccasin", "NavajoWhite", "Navy",
    "OldLace", "Olive", "OliveDrab", "Orange", "OrangeRed", "Orchid", "PaleGoldenRod", "PaleGreen",
    "PaleTurquoise", "PaleVioletRed", "PapayaWhip", "PeachPuff", "Peru", "Pink", "Plum", "PowderBlue",
    "Purple", "Red", "RosyBrown", "RoyalBlue", "SaddleBrown", "Salmon", "SandyBrown", "SeaGreen",
    "SeaShell", "Sienna", "Silver", "SkyBlue", "SlateBlue", "SlateGray", "SlateGrey", "Snow", "SpringGreen",
    "SteelBlue", "Tan", "Teal", "Thistle", "Tomato", "Turquoise", "Violet", "Wheat", "White", "WhiteSmoke",
    "Yellow", "YellowGreen"]
};
```